# Similarity score for arrays with high dimensional attributes

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, machine-learning, cosine-similarity

Hey everyone [first post, be gentle please :)]

I am trying to calculate the similarity scores between many arrays (thousands) so that I can create a 2D plot of similar arrays (something like `tSNE`).

The arrays are as follows:
Each array has a number of unique integers associated with it (probably 40-200 integers per object):

```
arr1 = [1513, 2354, 1929483, 323423...]

arr2 = [4546, 847, 993847, 8457...]

...

arrN = [236, 395828, 434535, 4369...]
```

Each unique integer can range from ~1-30,000,000. I want to compare each array with all other arrays to determine how many integers they have in common. This should be the basis of the similarity score, I imagine the comparison will result in an N x N matrix of similarity scores, although I would be interested to hear how you might reduce the N x N matrix to lower dimensionality.

Thanks for any help, I am not really sure where to start!

Comment: Sorting the arrays also allows for a cheaper (binary) search of matching elements; it may be worth is if the arrays are huge and the number of matching elements is small.

Answer (score 2):

If memory is not an issue, I'd convert all the arrays into sets and then compare their hashes, e.g.:

```
arr1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101]
arr2 = [47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149]

arr1_arr2_same = set(arr1) & set(arr2)

print("arr1 vs arr2, same elements: {}\n\tTotal: {}".format(arr1_arr2_same, len(arr1_arr2_same)))

# prints:
# arr1 vs arr2, same elements: set([97, 67, 101, 71, 73, 79, 59, 83, 53, 89, 47, 61])
#    Total: 12
```

You can just loop over your arrays, collect these sets and store them (or a total number of them) in a desired matrix. Not sure what exactly you want to do with them, tho.

Comment: Thanks for this, it is definitely helpful. I am wondering what you would do though if memory overhead is an issue? Also I am planning on taking these similarity scores (ie 12 for the example you listed) and plotting them with something like tSNE to visualize the similarity network.